# Subfolder don't load the style.css

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a `.htaccess` file that redirects all the URL request to my `index.php`

```
AcceptPathInfo On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Projects/tester/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Inside my index.php I have a code that include the URL file:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['request'])){
    include('pages/'.$_GET['request'].'.php');
}else{
    echo 'index';
}

?>
```

If my URL is `localhost/Projects/tester/green` my index will include a file called `green.php` that exists inside the folder `pages`.

inside pages/green.php I have this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div id="greenBox">
This box is green!
</div>
```

When I run that URL I can see a large green div with an text inside.

Great, now lets create a folder called `subs` inside the folder `pages` and create a file called `yellow.php`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div id="yellowBox">
This box is yellow!
</div>
```

When I run this URL `localhost/Projects/tester/sub/yellow` I can see the text but the `style.css` don't load (I can't see the yellow div).

If all the content is being included in the `index.php` and `style.css` file is in the same folder as the `index.php`, why `green.php` can load the `style.css` but the `yellow.php` not?

I can see the yellow div only if I add `../style.css` inside the yellow.php, but if it is to work on this way, I believe we should use `../style.css` on green.php while in yellow.php use `../../style.css`, no?

Is there a way to solve this? is problem in .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the external browser doesn't understand where your files are located on the server, so if you are in the following situation (from the browser's perspective):

```
http://localhost/Projects/tester/green
 -> hey browser, load "style.css"
 -> browser loads http://localhost/Projects/tester/style.css
```

But if you change the "virtual" path:

```
http://localhost/Projects/tester/sub/yellow
 -> hey browser, load "style.css"
 -> browser loads http://localhost/Projects/tester/sub/style.css
```

So you have three solutions here, in order of my personal preference:

1) Use absolute URLs for loading css data, optionally using a PHP var:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Projects/tester/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $base_path; ?>/style.css">
```

2) Use the <base> html element in head: (**warning:** it applies to ALL relative urls in the page: links, images, etc.)

```
<head>
  <base href="http://localhost/Projects/tester/" />
</head>
```

3) If using absolute URLs is not an option, you can calculate how many "virtual subdirectories" you are down and generate a prefix like this:

```
<?php
// first calculate $virtal_subdirs_number
$relative_urls = str_repeat("../", $virtual_subdirs_number);
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $relative_urls; ?>/style.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because the style.css is in parent directory of yellow.php, So for accessing a file in parent directory you must have to give path like ../style.css which mean look for it in one directory back and /style.css mean in the current directory which contain yellow.php